Trying to understand automatic OpenTelemetry instrumentation
I'm trying to set up a logging functionality in my NextJS app that comes with a trace- context compatibility. As I have experimented a little with the Pino Logger before, I'd like to continue using it for this matter.
This is my first time setting up a more sophisticated logging functionality, therefore I tried to research a bit beforehand and came across the OpenTelemetry Framework regarding the trace-context compatibility.
Apparently, it supports NextJS with some tweaks and also Pino.
Now, I'm still having trouble to understand which parts of the logging functionality you have to implement by yourself and which not. That is for example when you try to facilitate your implementation by using automatic instrumentation.
I'm trying to follow and understand this MWE on the official documentation for the use of OpenTelemetry together with Pino: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js-contrib/tree/main/plugins/node/opentelemetry-instrumentation-pino#usage
If you use an instrumentation such the one from above, do you still have to manually setup the span-context for every 'process flow' there might be in your app? Like implement the following code snippet from the MWE for every 'process' in your app:
const tracer = api.trace.getTracer('example');
tracer.startActiveSpan('manual-span', span => {
  logger.info('in a span');
  // 2. Fields identifying the current span will be added to log records:
  //    {"level":30,...,"msg":"in a span","trace_id":"d61b4e4af1032e0aae279d12f3ab0159","span_id":"d140da862204f2a2","trace_flags":"01"}
  //    This feature is called "log correlation".
});

I was assuming that you would just normally log at the places in your app that you'd want to (e.g. logger.info("This is a log message")) and the OpenTelemetry instrumentation would then take over and inject all the trace and span context information into the pino logs.
Am I wrong at this point?
If so, is it really necessary to start a new span everytime for every process that might be triggered due to a client request and keep track of the trace and span id?
I hope my question is somewhat clear. I'm still searching a more hands-on example on how to setup OpenTelemetry together with Pino in a Next/NodeJS app.
Thanks for the help!
